# Bug with setting currentPageIndicatorTintColor

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have custom view with scrollview and pageContoll.

```
let backScrollView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("BackScrollView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! BackScrollView
```

i try setting currentPageIndicatorTintColor

```
if brightnes > 200
{
   backScrollView.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
else
{
   backScrollView.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

I run this code on iPhone 5S (iOS 9.2), and code works without problems, but when i run this code on iPhone 5 (iOS 8.4) i become error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond
>   bounds for empty array'

I know that the error is in this line of code

```
backScrollView.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

I is calculated by using print.

What i doing wrong?

Comment: "I know that the error is in this line of code" I'm not sure you do know that. Can you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable reason is that either your page control has `numberOfPages` equal to 0, or `currentPage` is invalid (equal to -1).

Can you try the following

```
let pageControl = backScrollView.pageControl

if (pageControl.numberOfPages > 0 && pageControl.currentPage >= 0 && pageControl.currentPage < pageControl.numberOfPages) {
    if brightnes > 200 {
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    } else {
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
} else {
    print("Invalid pageControl state : numberOfPages = \(pageControl.numberOfPages); currentPage = \(pageControl.currentPage)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You was right! In iOS 8 before setting currentPageIndicatorTintColor need set numberOfPages and current Page! That's bullshit!